# Is it possible to call macro from cell editor?

Tags: excel

I have some macros that let me navigate among the open workbooks and their sheets in Excel. I have assigned these macros to ctrl-key combinations. But these don't work when I am editing a formula in a cell. That's a pity, because when I edit I typically want to navigate somewhere to point out a cell reference to use in the cell formula.

Is it possible to call user defined macros when you edit a cell? If so, what is the most convenient way?

Comment: Alt+Tab is the way I use to navigate between workbooks...

Comment: You can not. The VBA engine is disabled when in edit mode.